# Android: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getResources() from the type View

Tags: java, android, static

I've got problem with my simple apliccation.
I don't want paste tons of code.
I've got class `Zaladuj` where i must load files using `getResources()`.

```
loading_screen = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Widok.getResources(),R.drawable.loading_screen);
```

On this line i've got error:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getResources() from the type View.

I put all classes codes here: http://www.pcyra.pl/badpanda
It's not a website, it's just folder with my project. I create instance of View in MainActivity, The error shows in class `Zaladuj` on line 50.

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) which recreates your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[getResources()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getResources%28%29) is not a static method. You need an instance of the `View` (or `Widok` in your case) to call it. Your best bet would be to add a parameter to your `Zaladuj` class that accepts a `Context` then use `getResources()` on that:

```
private Context context;
public Zaladuj(Context con)
{
    super()
    this.context = con
}

private void downloadResources() 
{
    //
      loading_screen = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.context.getResources(),R.drawable.loading_screen);
    //
    int count = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
    {
        try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: It's simple right? I tried all of answers... always some errors.
Can you show me what should I add to code?
I know I'm dumb... that's one and only question I ask here. I always try to find solution by myself.

Comment: I dove deeper into your code and found some things that don't make sense. You call `new Zaladuj(this)` in your `LoadingScreen` but you don't have any constructors implemented in you `Zaladuj` so you should not be able to compile because of this. That being said if you make the changes to `Zaladuj` I've already outlined and change your call to `new Zaladuj(this.getBaseContext).execute("BadPanda studio");` it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Since the `getResources()` method isn't `static`, you will need to create an instance of your `Widok` class to be able to call it, eg:

```
Widok widok = new Widok(context);
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(widok.getResources(),R.drawable.loading_screen);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is clearly telling you whats wrong.You are not allowed to call it with Widok.

If you are in activity class then call

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.loading_screen);
```

If you are in non-activity class then you will need Activity context.

Like if you are in AsyncTask then you would write something like this

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.loading_screen);
```

Just make sure you pass correct activity context in constructor.

Comment: It's simple right? I tried all of answers... always some errors.
Can you show me what should I add to code?
I know I'm dumb... that's one and only question I ask here. I always try to find solution by myself.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting that error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getResources() from the type View." is because the getResources() method is not a static method. In other words, you'll need to isntantiate a new Widok

```
Widok w = new Widok(context);
```

asnd then call the resources on that object

```
w.getResource();
```

**Edit

This is the code you'd put in your activity class. You pass the keyword "this" to the constructor of Widok which references the application context

```
Widok w = new Widok(this);
loading_screen = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(w.getResources(),R.drawable.loading_screen);
```

Comment: It's simple right? I tried all of answers... always some errors.
Can you show me what should I add to code?
I know I'm dumb... that's one and only question I ask here. I always try to find solution by myself.

Comment: I have got this line in my MainActivity class:
  `final Widok widoczek = new Widok(this);`
But i can't use widoczek.getResources() in my "Zaladuj" class... <br /> that's the point!